# Rails project after db:create, error message: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundle-install

I git cloned a project and, after `bundle install`, I tried a `db:create` but I have this error message. Does anyone know where it is coming from?

> ➜  ******* git:(master) ✗ bundle exec rake db:create
>   [2.3.0] dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   __ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1_
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/zato/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/init.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found:
>   __ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1_
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/zato/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/init.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace

Comment: Could you be specific? What project did you clone? You might have missed something.

Comment: This seems like a conflict of `v8`, `libv8` or `therubyracer` versions. Is it possible that you have multiple versions of some of these packages installed? Have a look [here](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/94).

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue. Fairly new rails app setup. Trying to generate a controller when i get that message. I was initially using the homebrew v8, but i tried removing it and therubyracer gem. Now though when installing therubyracer, it cant find the v8.h file. I have xcode installed, as i do some react native development on this machine as well.